# How to apply Indent to array json in java

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson, json-arrayagg

We are reading the file changing the content and writing back to the same location.

How to apply indentation to a JSON array in java/only specific properties?

Source code:

```java
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.internal.Streams;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

String file="D:\\Documents\\read.json";     
JsonElement root = Streams.parse(new JsonReader(new FileReader(file)));
// changing the json values here
try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(writer);
    jsonWriter.setIndent("\t");
    Streams.write(root, jsonWriter);
    jsonWriter.flush();
}  catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

What we have:

```json
{
  "array": ["element 1","element 2","element 3" ],
  "object": {
    "property1": "value1",
    "property2":"value2"
  }
}
```

Code generated:

```json
{
    "array": [
        "element 1",
        "element 2",
        "element 3"
    ],
    "object": {
        "property1": "value1",
        "property2": "value2"
    }
}
```

What we need

```json
{
  "array": ["element 1","element 2","element 3" ],
  "object": {
    "property1": "value1",
    "property2":"value2"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible in Gson using the standard `JsonWriter` implementation. You can try to extend `JsonWriter` manage indents based on the current write state/path. Not sure it worth doing so though.

Answer (score 0):

The usual JSON serializers don't offer selective indentation. Most offer "pretty-printing" (generating output that is not all on one line) targeted at human readers. In general this is not even needed, as the different outputs are sematically equal and JSON is meant for machines to read/write and machines do not care about indentation. Pretty-printing is only supported as a convenience in case a human needs to debug it.

The only solution I can offer is to write your own serializer, but this is not as easy as it might seem, except for the most simple cases.

Comment: can you please share the code if possible

Comment: I don't have any code to share as I wouldn't ever attempt to do it this way. As said, JSON is for machines to consume and they don 't care about the whitespace. Why do you?